# Do I have to use more than one module for an excel with more than one sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Do I have to use more than one module for an excel with more than one sheet?
Or can I just create a single module with generic functions that are suited for every individual entity in each sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single module is fine and it's functions will be callable from any sheet or sheet module.
If you start having a lot of code, you can create more modules. Personnaly I try to keep generic, reusable code apart from workbook specific code. This way I can easily export/import my *general use* modules